# Спавн пули относительно оружия

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с такой проблемой:
Есть космический корабль, у него есть дочерние объекты - орудия на нужных позициях. Но пули спавнятся не там где нужно:
До начала игры, пушки еще не заспавнились:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
в игре, пушки на своих местах, но пули нет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно решить эту проблему?

Исходный код:

```
//class WeaponPoint
public void SetWeapon(GameObject weaponPrefab, Quaternion rotation, Transform parrent = null)
{
    this.weaponPrefab = weaponPrefab;
    if (weaponPrefab == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Weapon prefab must be not null!");
    }

    GameObject instanceWeapon = LeanPool.Spawn
(weaponPrefab, weaponPointCoords, rotation, parrent); 
//weaponPointCoords = vector2 с координатами точки спавна для оружия, указываются через конструктор, класс не наследует MonoBehaviour  
//Other code
}

//Пример вызова метода установки оружия
weaponPoints[i].SetWeapon(weaponPrefabs, this.transform.rotation, this.transform);
```

Далее мне нужно заспавнить пулю/пули относительно позиции оружия

```
    //class Weapon
    private void SingleModAttack()
    {
        //Координаты спавна пули(вот тут проблема)
        Vector2 spawnBulletPoint = this.transform.position;
        spawnBulletPoint.y++;
        GameObject bulletInst = LeanPool.Spawn(bulletPrefab, spawnBulletPoint, transform.rotation);
        Bullet bulletComponent = bulletInst.GetComponent<Bullet>();
        if (bulletComponent == null)
        {
            throw new MissingComponentException
                ("Missing \"Bullet\" component in bullet prefab!");
        }

        bulletComponent.Damage = damage;
        bulletComponent.DestroyBullet(2f);
    }
```

Comment: Что вы ожидаете от этой строчки `this.transform.TransformPoint(this.transform.position)`? `transform.position` - положение объекта в world space, зачем вы эти координаты переводите из локального пространства в глобальное?

Comment: Также стоит укажите, где у вас в сцене центр мировых координат.

Comment: 0, 0 почти там, где спавнятся пули на картинке, у самой пули получается -0.7 по x. Просто даже если использовать просто transform.position, то результат тот-же - пули в том-же месте, а не возле пушек. Поэтому я и подумал, что проблема, наверно, с локальными и глобальными координатами. InverseTransformPoint() дает тот-же результат.

Comment: Ну для начала тут нужно использовать просто transform.position, ничего никуда переводить не нужно. Вы уверены, что орудия корабля спавнятся там, где нужно? Приведите пример инстанциирования такого орудия.

Comment: Да пушки на своих местах, скрины в вопросе, пример как создаются пушки тоже там, метод SetWeapon в классе WeaponPoint(не является монобехавор), координаты WeaponPoint задаются через конструктор, по этим координатам спавнятся пушки.

Comment: Не поверю, если вы скажете, что 'Vector2 spawnBulletPoint = this.transform.position;' **не** исправило проблему. И лучше не надо исправлять ошибки в вопросе - другие люди в будущем не поймут, о чем шла речь в комментариях.

Comment: "И лучше не надо исправлять ошибки в вопросе - другие люди в будущем не поймут, о чем шла речь в комментариях," - спасибо учту.
Проблема была не в координатах спавна.

Comment: Если вы решили вопрос самостоятельно - следует оформит ответ для других людей :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, просто в методе Attack() класса WeaponPoint я брал компонент Weapon и делегировал ему работу метода(weapon.Attack() - в нем создается пуля и т.д.).
Загвоздка была в том, что компонент Weapon я брал у префаба пушки, а не инстанса, соответственно пули спавнилась по координатам префаба =\
П.с - будет уроком выкладывать исходники полностью)